# How to generate an IPA for IOS project

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, apk

I build a `Xamarin Forms` application and I am using VMware to run my ios project. I generated an APK for android successfully, but I don't know how to generate IPA for the IOS project. Any idea?

Comment: in ios not generate apk it's generate .ipa file.

Answer (score 2):

iOS executable file format is ipa, not APK.

[Here is documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/introduction-to-xamarin-ios-for-visual-studio) about building iOS ipa using xamarin.

You need MacOs to compile Mac based binary files :

- Use a Mac as your main development machine and run a Windows virtual machine with Visual Studio installed. using VM software such as Parallels or VMWare .
- Use a Mac just as a build host. In this scenario it would be connected to the same network as a Windows machine with the necessary tools installed.

Comment: This should be a comment. If you want to convert it to an answer please provide more detailed information. Link may die one day and then "this answer" will be pointless.

Answer (score 2):

Using below steps you can generate IPA for ios:

1. Connect your project with Mac using VMWare.
2. Select Release mode instead of Debug:

[image: Select Release]

3. Right click on your iOS Project and go to properties.
4. Then go to iOS Bundle Signing and select appropriate Provisional
   Profile and Certificate.
5. Then move to next option i.e.iOS IPA Options and Mark checkbox true
   name with Build iTunes Package Archive(IPA).
6. Add Package name as per your Certificate.
7. Now Just clean and Build your Project for iPhone mode

[image: Build for iPhone].

You can find your IPA in your release/iPhone folder.

Comment: I tried your answer but I keep getting this error: No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain. You need to request a codesigning certificate from https://developer.apple.com. AppXamarin.iOS

Comment: Yes. You need to create certificate on provided link and add into your mac keychain.